# Oracle SQL - Calculate number of concurrent phone calls

Tags: sql, oracle

First of all, I am not very experienced with SQL. I have found similar questions here before but so far I was not able to develop a working solution for my specific problem.

I have a table that holds phone call records which has the following fields:

```
 END: Holds the timestamp of when a call ended - Data Type: DATE
 LINE: Holds the phone line that was used for a call - Data Type: NUMBER
 CALLDURATION: Holds the duration of a call in seconds - Data Type: NUMBER
```

The table has entries like this:

```
END                    LINE                CALLDURATION
---------------------- ------------------- -----------------------
25/01/2012 14:05:10    6                   65
25/01/2012 14:08:51    7                   1142
25/01/2012 14:20:36    5                   860
```

I need to create a query that returns the number of concurrent phone calls based on the data from that table. The query should be capable of calculating that number in fixed intervals, such as every 5 minutes.
To make this more clear, here is an example of what the query should return (based on the example entries from the previous table:

```
TIMESTAMP              CURRENTLYUSEDLINES          
---------------------- -------------------
25/01/2012 14:05:00    2
25/01/2012 14:10:00    1
25/01/2012 14:15:00    1
```

How can I do this with a (Oracle) SQL query? There are currently almost 1 million records in the table so the query must be as fast as possible because otherwise it would take forever to execute it.

Comment: Create a help table that stores all timestamps. Join/left join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be this one:

```
WITH t AS
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-01-25 14:00:00' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '5' MINUTE AS TS
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY TIMESTAMP '2012-01-25 14:00:00' + LEVEL * INTERVAL '5' MINUTE <= TIMESTAMP '2012-01-25 14:15:00'),
calls AS 
    (SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-01-25 14:05:10' AS END_TIME, 6 AS LINE, 65 AS duration FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-01-25 14:08:51', 7, 1142 FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-01-25 14:20:36', 5, 860 FROM dual)
SELECT TS, count(distinct line)
FROM t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN calls ON ts BETWEEN END_TIME - duration * INTERVAL '1' SECOND AND END_TIME
GROUP BY ts
HAVING count(distinct line) > 0
ORDER BY ts;

TS                   COUNT(DISTINCTLINE)
-------------------- -------------------
25.01.2012 14:05:00                    2
25.01.2012 14:10:00                    1
25.01.2012 14:15:00                    1

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thanks! That solution works just fine. Since I forgot to mention that results with 0 used lines can be filtered out, I changed the query so it looks like this:

SELECT * FROM
(
 WITH t AS
 ...
 SELECT TIMESTAMP, count(distinct LINE) AS USED_LINES
 ...
 ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
)
WHERE USED_LINES > 0

However I'm not sure if this is an efficient way to do this and the query takes quite a while to execute (up to an hour or more for all data in the table + small intervals). Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that HAVING existed. It runs about as fast as the older query though since I guess it does pretty much the same things internally for both statements. Let me know if you have any ideas for making this even faster since it might be too slow to process all entries that are currently in the table for short intervals like a minute or less. Other than that it does exactly what it should already :)